# Filter table view with checkboxes, mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, checkbox

Got stuck with an problem i hoping you can help me with.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and have made an MVC Project that show tv-Channels
I have a table in my database (full) that store all my data for my 5 channels, it look something like this:

```
Id    Channel     Program         Date          Time
1       One         News         2018-11-11     18:00
2       One         Sport        2018-11-11     20:00
3       Two         Inception    2018-11-11     09:50
4       Three       Seinfeldt    2018-11-11     11.00
5       Four        Alf          2018-11-11     15:30
5       Four        News         2018-11-11     19:00
.
.
.
```

**This is my Controller**

```
namespace Uppgift4.Controllers
{
public class FullsController : Controller
{
    private TvProgramDBEntities db = new TvProgramDBEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.Full);
    }
```

**This is My View**

```
@model IEnumerable<Uppgift4.Models.Full>
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<tr>
    <th>
        Channel
    </th>
    <th>
        Program
    </th>
    <th>
        Date
    </th>
    <th>
        Time
    </th>
    <th></th>
 </tr>

 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Channel)
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Program)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Time)
        </td>
    </tr>
 }
```

This works fine and i get a list of all my programs in my view.

Now i want to filter this table, by adding 5 checkboxes(one for each channel), so i can choose which channel i want to show data from. So when i for example check One and two i just get the programs for this two channels in my view, How can i add this feature in my view?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, so when 2 check-boxes are checked you actually want the remaining to disappear from view? Or is it like you want to save to database the selected channels and then when retrieving next time, load the view with all channels along with the selected channels as highlighted/checked?

Comment: Hi. sorry for unclear question. When i check two boxes (and let say push a button) the result get filtert and the other chennels dissapear. Because i want to make an personal tv-tableau (with login) i want the result to be saves also, so the next time i login to that account my preference are remembered

Comment: But the main fokus right now i try to solve is to be able to filter the table, making the personal login is step two :-) @Jeshwel